# Shopware 6 plugin: Config value is incorrect after update due to removed config key

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a plugin that handles a configuration value for auto-publishing reviews (`reviewModeration`). In version 1.6.3, I added a new config key `autoPublishStars`. Furthermore, I want to totally remove `reviewModeration` in version 1.6.4.

`config.xml`

```xml
        <input-field type="bool">
            <name>reviewSkipModeration</name>
            <label>Accept reviews automatically</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Bewertungen automatisch freigeschaltet</label>
            <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </input-field>
        <input-field type="single-select">
            <name>autoPublishStars</name>
            <label>Auto Publish review with stars</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Sterne vorausgewählt</label>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
            <options>
                <option>
                    <id>None</id>
                    <name>None</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">Keine</name>
                </option>                
                <option>
                    <id>0</id>
                    <name>0 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">0 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>1 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">1 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>2 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">2 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>3 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">3 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>4 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">4 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>5 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">5 Sterne</name>
                </option>
            </options>
        </input-field>
```

The update function contains logic to migrate the old config to the new config:

```php
  public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
        
        // Get the currently installed version
        $version = $context->getCurrentPluginVersion(); 

        // Only update config if on version 1.6.3 or higher
        if (version_compare($version, '1.6.3', '>=')) {
            // Get config service from the container
            $configService = $this->container->get('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService');       
        
            // Get the current value of the configuration
            $previousConfigVal  = $configService->getBool('SwagPlugin.config.reviewModeration');
            $newConfigVal = $previousConfigVal ? '0' : 'None';
               
            // Set the specified value as default
            $configService->set('SwagPlugin.config.autoPublishStars', $newConfigVal);     
        }
    }
```

This works fine when updating from 1.6.2 -> 1.6.3. However, when updating from 1.6.3 -> 1.6.4, since the old key`reviewModeration` no longer exists, it sets `autoPublishStars` the `None` value regardless of the previous value of the `autoPublishStars`:

- User has `reviewModeration` enabled (true) in v1.6.2
- Update to v1.6.3 migrates true to new key `autoPublishStars`
- Update to v1.6.4 checks old key `reviewModeration`, `autoPublishStars` gets false, inverts value
- v1.6.4 sets `autoPublishStars` to false even though true in v1.6.3

How can I prevent this incorrect toggling when refactoring config keys across plugin versions? I only want to read the old key on the first update, not on subsequent ones. The first update version could be v1.7.8 (not necessarily 1.6.3) for example when the user updates from 1.1.1 to straight 1.7.8.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
    parent::update($context);

    // Get the currently installed version
    $version = $context->getCurrentPluginVersion();

    // Get config service from the container
    $configService = $this->container->get('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService');

    // Check if the migration has already been performed
    $migrationFlag = $configService->get('SwagPlugin.config.migrationFlag');

    if (version_compare($version, '1.6.3', '>=') && !$migrationFlag) {
        // Perform the migration only if on version 1.6.3 or higher
        $previousConfigVal  = $configService->getBool('SwagPlugin.config.reviewModeration');
        $newConfigVal = $previousConfigVal ? '0' : 'None';

        // Set the specified value as default
        $configService->set('SwagPlugin.config.autoPublishStars', $newConfigVal);

        // Set the migration flag to indicate that the migration has been performed
        $configService->set('SwagPlugin.config.migrationFlag', true);
    }
}
```

With this approach, the migration will only be performed on the first update to version 1.6.3 or higher, and subsequent updates won't trigger it again.

Remember to adjust the version numbers and configuration keys according to your specific use case and plugin structure.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me how does this `migrationFlag` work? I mean do I need to create a new config field with name `migrationFlag`?

Comment: yes, you will create a new config called migrationFlag and make the default value false so that when you update as a result of the process, it returns true and does not repeat the update

Comment: I have asked a new question. Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77180656/22289437