# Shopware 6 Plugin: Why do I need to click the save button twice to create a new entry?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, shopware, shopware6

I'm working on a Shopware 6 Plugin, and I'm facing an issue with the save functionality. Specifically, when I click the save button, it requires me to click it twice in order to create a new entry in my system.

I have a Twig template with a save button:

```html
<sw-button-process
    v-bind:isLoading="isLoading"
    v-bind:processSuccess="processSuccess"
    variant="primary"
    @process-finish="saveFinish"
    @click="onClickSave">
    {{ $t('plugin-entity.saveButtonText') }}
</sw-button-process>
```

In my Twig Template's `onClickSave` method, I initiate a save operation using the Shopware API. However, it seems that the save operation is not working as expected, as I need to click the button twice to get it to work properly.

Here's the `onClickSave` method:

```js
        onClickSave() {
            this.isLoading = true;

            this.repository
                    .save(this.blacklist, Shopware.Context.api)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.getBlacklist();
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.processSuccess = true;
                    })
                    .catch((exception) => {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.createNotificationError({
                            title: this.$t('plugin-entity.errorTitle'),
                            message: exception
                        });
                    });
        },
```

I think that there might be an issue with my save logic. Could someone please help me understand why I have to click the save button twice to create a new entry successfully?

Any help is appreacted.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console and does your request show up in the network log after the first click?

Comment: @Ezycod, There are no errors in the console. After the first click, I see this in the network log: `25 9d417a POST xhr 204 http://localhost/api/plugin-entity 91 ms
26 7102b8 POST xhr 200 http://localhost/api/search/plugin-entity 34 ms` And after the second click, I see `50 657f8b POST xhr 200 http://localhost/api/search/plugin.entity 72 ms`. it looks like the main difference between the first and second click is that the entity is not being saved on the first click.

On first click, I see a 204 response. On second click, I see 200 responses.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be fine, did you try to refresh the page manually after clicking save only once? there might just be an issue with refreshing your current view.

Comment: Yes, I found the issue. Actually, my create component and detail component both contain the `onClickSave()` methods. The `onClickSave()` method of create component has a router push to the detail component along with the ID. I just removed this router and moved the logic from detail to create component.

Comment: @Ezycod kindly, have a look at my other question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77185810/22289437