# Vue.JS/Shopware 6 Plugin: Delete confirmation modal not showing in custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom component in Shopware 6 where I want to show a delete confirmation modal when the user clicks the delete action. However, the modal is not popping up when delete is clicked.

`my-component.html.twig`:

```html
{% block custom_list %}
    <sw-page class="custom_list">

        {% block custom_list_smart_bar_header %}
            <template slot="smart-bar-header">
                {% block custom_list_smart_bar_header_title %}
                    <h2>
                        {% block custom_list_smart_bar_header_title_text %}
                            {{ $t('custom_list.general.mainMenuItemGeneral') }}
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block custom_list_smart_bar_header_amount %}
                            <span v-if="!isLoading" class="sw-page__smart-bar-amount">
                                ({{ blacklist.total }})
                            </span>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </h2>
                {% endblock %}
            </template>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block custom_list_smart_bar_actions %}
            <template slot="smart-bar-actions">
                {% block custom_list_smart_bar_actions_create %}
                    <sw-button variant="primary" v-bind:routerLink="{ name: 'custom_list.create' }">
                        {{ $t('custom_list.buttonAddEntry') }}
                    </sw-button>
                {% endblock %}
            </template>
        {% endblock %}

        <template slot="content">
            {% block plugin_entry_content %}
                <sw-entity-listing
                    v-if="templist"
                    v-bind:items="templist"
                    v-bind:repository="repository"
                    v-bind:showSelection="false"
                    v-bind:columns="columns">  
                    
  <template slot="actions" slot-scope="{ item }">

    <sw-context-menu-item 
      variant="danger"
      @click="onDelete(item)"
    >
      Delete
    </sw-context-menu-item>

  </template>
</template>
   {% block plugin_entry_modal_delete %}
        <sw-modal
            v-if="showEntryDeleteModal"
            variant="small"
            :title="Cancel"
            @modal-close="onCancelEntryDelete"
        >

            {% block plugin_entry_modal_delete_body %}
            <p>asda</p>
            {% endblock %}


            {% block plugin_entry_modal_delete_footer %}
            <template #modal-footer>

                {% block plugin_modal_delete_button_cancel %}
                <sw-button
                    size="small"
                    @click="onCancelEntryDelete"
                >
                    <p>asda</p>
                </sw-button>
                {% endblock %}

                {% block plugin_modal_delete_button_confirm %}
                <sw-button
                    size="small"
                    variant="danger"
                    @click="onConfirmEntryDelete"
                >
                     <p>asda</p>
                </sw-button>
                {% endblock %}
            </template>
            {% endblock %}
        </sw-modal>
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
   </sw-page>
            
{% endblock %}
```

And in my component's script `index.js`:

```js
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: false,
            repository: null,
            blacklist: null,
            showEntryDeleteModal: false,
            deleteEntryId: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
    loadItems() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.repository.search(new Shopware.Data.Criteria(), Shopware.Context.api).then((result) => {
           this.blacklist = result;
           this.isLoading = false;
       });
    },
    
    onDelete(item) {
      this.deleteEntryId = item.id;  
      this.onShowEntryDeleteModal();
    },
    
    onCancelEntryDelete() {
            this.deleteEntryId = null;
            this.onCloseEntryDeleteModal();
        },
    
    onShowEntryDeleteModal() {
            this.showEntryDeleteModal = true;
    },
    
    onCloseEntryDeleteModal() {
            this.showEntryDeleteModal = false;
    },
    onConfirmEntryDelete() {
      this.onCloseEntryDeleteModal();  
       
      this.repository.delete(this.deleteEntryId,  Shopware.Context.api)
        .then(() => {
          this.deleteEntryId = null;  
          this.loadItems();
        });
    }
  },
```

When I click the `Delete` action in the listing, I expected it to set `showDeleteModal` to true and display the modal, but the modal does not show. What am I missing in order to get the delete confirmation modal to properly open when the delete action is clicked?

Comment: Your `onDelete` methods call the `onShowEntryDeleteModal` method, which does not exist, or at least in your provided code. You really should use the console more often if that is the case.

Comment: @Ezycod hello, I have updated the code. But the delete modal does not show up.

Comment: @Ezycod I want to implement the delete functionality as being done in here "https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ddc98f69d6ed3e2be7a84c71d1be47b9c00f520a/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-product/view/sw-product-detail-reviews/index.js#L6"

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors right now, did you check your call stack with some `console.log()` outputs, to check if everything gets called?
And post your whole template please, there might be some issues there.

Comment: Yes, The function calls go to specific functions I have checked from `console.log()`. Secondly, I have a question can my ` </sw-page>` tag stop the modal from popping up?

Comment: @Ezycod I have also updated the question with the whole template.

Comment: Your modal is not placed inside the `content` slot of the `sw-page` component, so it is probably ignored ant won't be rendered at all.

Comment: @Ezycod I have asked another question. Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77243008/22289437