# Shopware 6 plugin: Emails still being sent to blocked recipients

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I'm using the `SwagProductReviews`plugin to send review request emails to customers after they place an order. This plugin uses a scheduled task to send the emails.

I want to integrate the `EmailBlackList` plugin to prevent emails from being sent to blacklisted customers. The Email Blacklist plugin contains a list of email addresses that should not receive emails in a table.

In my `SendProductReviewsInvitationTaskHandler.php`

```php
    public function run(): void {
        try {
            $cronContext = Context::createDefaultContext();

            $originalConfig = $this->mailHelper->getConfig();

            $this->log('Schedules Task start');

            $criteria = new Criteria();
            $criteria->addAssociation('languages');
            /** @var \Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelEntity[] $salesChannels */
            $salesChannels = $this->salesChannelRepository->search($criteria, $cronContext);

            $this->log(count($salesChannels) . ' SalesChannels');
            foreach ($salesChannels as $salesChannel) {
                $salesChannelOrdersSent = 0;
                $this->mailHelper->setConfig($this->configService->getSalesChannelConfig($salesChannel->getId()));
                if (!$this->mailHelper->getConfig()->isActive()) {
                    $this->log($salesChannel->getName() . ' is not active in the plugin config. skipping.');
                    continue;
                }
                $this->log('Checking orders for ' . $salesChannel->getName());

                /** @var \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEntity[] $orders */
                $orders = $this->mailHelper->getInvitationOrders($cronContext, $salesChannel);
                $this->log(count($orders) . ' orders found');
                foreach ($orders as $order) {
                    if ($this->mailHelper->sendInvitationMail($cronContext, $order)) {
                        $this->log($order->getOrderNumber() . ' invitation sent', ['id' => $order->getId()]);
                        $salesChannelOrdersSent++;
                    }
                }
                $this->log($salesChannelOrdersSent . ' invitations sent in SalesChannel ' . $salesChannel->getName(), [], Logger::INFO);
            }
            $this->mailHelper->setConfig($originalConfig);
            $this->log('Schedules Task done');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e);
        }
    }
```

My `sendInvitationMail` function in `MailHelper.php` class in the `SwagProductReviews` plugin looks like:

```php
    public function sendInvitationMail(Context $outerContext, OrderEntity $order, bool $testMail = false): bool {
        try {
            $message = null;
            $context = $this->getOrderContext($outerContext, $order);
            if (!is_null($order->getLineItems()) && count($order->getLineItems()) > 0 && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()) && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail()) && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()->getCustomerId())) {
                if ($this->orderService->allProductsRated($order, $outerContext)) {
                    $this->markInvitationAsAlreadyRated($order, $outerContext);
                    if (!$testMail) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                $data = $this->prepareMailTemplate(MailHelperInterface::MAIL_TEMPLATE_INVITATION, $context, $order, $testMail);
                $salesChannel = $this->getSalesChannel($context, $order);

                if (!$testMail) {
                    $data->set(
                        'recipients',
                        [
                            $order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail() => $order->getOrderCustomer()->getFirstName() . ' ' . $order->getOrderCustomer()->getLastName(),
                        ]
                    );

                    if ($this->getConfig()->isSendInvitationCopy()) {
                        $storeOwnerEmail = $this->getStoreOwnerEmail();
                        $data->set('recipientsBcc', $storeOwnerEmail);
                    }
                }

                $helper = new SwagProductReviewsHelper();
                $orderHash = $helper->getOrderHash($order);
                $hashShort = substr($orderHash, 0, 6);

                $message = $this->sendMail(
                    $data->all(),
                    $context,
                    [
                        'order' => $order,
                        'salesChannel' => $salesChannel,
                        'hash' => $hashShort
                    ],
                    $testMail
                );

                if (!is_null($message)) {
                    if (!$testMail) {
                        $this->markInvitationAsSent($order, $context);
                        $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::INFO, 'Invitation Mail sent and order marked as sent.', ['message' => $message, 'Order id' => $order->getId(), 'Order Number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::ERROR, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . '. No mailer message.', ['Order id' => $order->getId()]);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $this->markInvitationAsSent($order, $context);
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::ERROR, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . '. No valid LineItems or Customer Data. Marked es sent.', ['Order id' => $order->getId()]);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . ' with order id ' . $order->getId());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My `sendMail` function in `MailHelper.php` class in the `SwagProductReviews` plugin is:

```php
    public function sendMail(array $data, Context $context, array $templateData = [], bool $testMail = false): ?Email {
        $email = $data['email'];
        if (!$testMail && !$this->getConfig()->isSendMails() && $this->isEmailBlacklisted($email, $context)) {
            $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Sending Mail blocked by configuration.');
            return null;
        }

        if ($testMail) {
            $this->saveTemplateData($context, $data['technicalName'], $templateData);
        }

        return $this->getMailService()->send(
            $data,
            $context,
            $templateData
        );
    }
```

I have an `EmailBlackList` plugin that sends transactional emails like review invitations and notifications. I implemented the `isEmailBlacklisted` function like this:

In my `MailHelperWithBlacklist.php`

```php
    /**
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $templateData
     * @return Email|null
     */
    public function sendMail(array $data, Context $context, array $templateData = [], bool $testMail = false): ?Email {
        // Get email from data
        $email = $data['email'];
        if ($this->isEmailBlacklisted($email, $context)) {
            $this->inner->getLoggerHelper()->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Mail blocked by Blacklist');
            return null;
        }

        // If not blacklisted, proceed to send the email
        return $this->inner->sendMail($data, $context, $templateData, $testMail);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param string $email
     * @param Context $context
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isEmailBlacklisted(string $email, Context $context): bool
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('email', $email));

        $blacklistEntry = $this->blacklistRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();

        return $blacklistEntry !== null;
    }
```

My goal is that if a customer's email is found in the blacklist, the scheduled task should not send the review request email. However, it should still mark the order as "Email sent" so that the order is not picked up again on the next run of the task.

The problem is that even with emails in my blacklist and the above checks in place, emails are still being received by blocked recipients

How can I make my `SwagProductReviews` Plugin fire some kind of event when the `SwagProductReviews` Plugin tries to send a email via `SendProductReviewsInvitationTaskHandler.php`?

The blacklist plugin should listen to the event and return a `true`/`false` that allows the `SwagProductReviews` plugin to react accordingly.

Comment: Did you actually verify, that the method `isEmailBlacklisted` is returning the correct (and expected) result?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, it works as expected. It returns true when the email is blacklisted otherwise it returns false.

Comment: Did you check that your `MailHelperWithBlacklist::sendMail` function is actually called?  Maybe the decorator is not working?

Comment: @Alex, How can I check (test) whether the decorator is working or not?

Comment: With xdebug, or some logging, or eventually somethink like `die('I am here')` on your dev machine.

Comment: @Alex yes it the decorator is not working. How can I make my SwagProductReviews Plugin fire some kind of filter event that allows the blacklist plugin to register on that? The blacklist plugin should listen to the event and return a true/false that allows the reviews plugin to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an event `ReviewInvitationEmailEvent` in the `SwagProductReviews`  plugin.

```php
class ReviewInvitationEmailEvent implements ShopwareEvent
{
    /** @var string */
    private $email;

    /** @var SalesChannelEntity */
    private $salesChannel;

    /** @var Context */
    private $context;
    
    /** @var bool */
    private $blocked;
  
    public function __construct(string $email, SalesChannelEntity $salesChannel, Context $context)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->salesChannel = $salesChannel;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->blocked = false;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getSalesChannel(): SalesChannelEntity 
    {
        return $this->salesChannel;
    }

    public function getContext(): Context
    {
        return $this->context;
    }
    
    public function block(): void 
    {
        $this->blocked = true;
    }
  
    public function isBlocked(): bool
    {
        return $this->blocked;
    }
    public function toArray(): array {
    return [
        'email' => $this->email,
        'salesChannel' => $this->salesChannel,
        'context' => $this->context,
    ];
 }
}
```

2. Dispatch an event before sending the email in the `MailHelper.php` file.

```php
    public function sendInvitationMail(Context $outerContext, OrderEntity $order, bool $testMail = false): bool {
        try {
            $message = null;
            $context = $this->getOrderContext($outerContext, $order);
            if (!is_null($order->getLineItems()) && count($order->getLineItems()) > 0 && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()) && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail()) && !is_null($order->getOrderCustomer()->getCustomerId())) {
                if ($this->orderService->allProductsRated($order, $outerContext)) {
                    $this->markInvitationAsAlreadyRated($order, $outerContext);
                    if (!$testMail) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                $data = $this->prepareMailTemplate(MailHelperInterface::MAIL_TEMPLATE_INVITATION, $context, $order, $testMail);
                $salesChannel = $this->getSalesChannel($context, $order);
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'In the sendInvitationMail');
                $email = $order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail();
                
                $event = new ReviewInvitationEmailEvent(
                $email,
                $salesChannel,
                $outerContext
                );
                
                $eventData = $event->toArray();
                
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::INFO, 'Dispatching event', ['eventData' => $eventData]);
                
                try {
                $dispatchedEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event); 
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Event dispatched',['dispatchedEvent' => $dispatchedEvent] );
                
                if ($event->isBlocked()) {
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::INFO, 'email is blocked');
                    return false; 
                }
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::INFO, 'email is not blocked', ['isBlocked' => $event->isBlocked()]);

                } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                    $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e, 'In the catch of event dispatcher '); 
                }
               

                if (!$testMail) {
                    $data->set(
                        'recipients',
                        [
                            $order->getOrderCustomer()->getEmail() => $order->getOrderCustomer()->getFirstName() . ' ' . $order->getOrderCustomer()->getLastName(),
                        ]
                    );

                    if ($this->getConfig()->isSendInvitationCopy()) {
                        $storeOwnerEmail = $this->getStoreOwnerEmail();
                        $data->set('recipientsBcc', $storeOwnerEmail);
                    }
                }

                $helper = new SwagProductReviewsHelper();
                $orderHash = $helper->getOrderHash($order);
                $hashShort = substr($orderHash, 0, 6);

                $message = $this->sendMail(
                    $data->all(),
                    $context,
                    [
                        'order' => $order,
                        'salesChannel' => $salesChannel,
                        'hash' => $hashShort
                    ],
                    $testMail
                );

                if (!is_null($message)) {
                    if (!$testMail) {
                        $this->markInvitationAsSent($order, $context);
                        $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::INFO, 'Invitation Mail sent and order marked as sent.', ['message' => $message, 'Order id' => $order->getId(), 'Order Number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::ERROR, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . '. No mailer message.', ['Order id' => $order->getId()]);
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $this->markInvitationAsSent($order, $context);
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::ERROR, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . '. No valid LineItems or Customer Data. Marked es sent.', ['Order id' => $order->getId()]);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e, 'Failed to send invitation for ' . $order->getOrderNumber() . ' with order id ' . $order->getId());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

3. Create an event subscriber `ReviewInvitationEmailSubscriber` that listens for the event `ReviewInvitationEmailEvent` and block if email is blacklisted in `EmailBlackList` plugin.

```php
class ReviewInvitationEmailSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected MailWithBlacklist $mailWithBlacklist; 
    protected LoggerHelper $loggerHelper;
    
    public function __construct(MailWithBlacklist $mailWithBlacklist, LoggerHelper $loggerHelper) {
        $this->mailWithBlacklist = $mailWithBlacklist;
        $this->loggerHelper = $loggerHelper;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ReviewInvitationEmailEvent::class => 'checkBlacklist'
        ];
    }

    public function checkBlacklist(ReviewInvitationEmailEvent $event) 
    {
        $email = $event->getEmail();
        $context = $event->getContext();
        

        $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Inside of checkBlacklist outside if');
        $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Inside of checkBlacklist email =' . $email);

        try{
            $tempBool = $this->mailWithBlacklist->isEmailBlacklisted($email, $context);
             $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'inside try block before the if statement of isEmailBlacklist'. $tempBool );
           if ($this->mailWithBlacklist->isEmailBlacklisted($email, $context)) {
                $this->loggerHelper->addDirectRecord(Logger::DEBUG, 'Inside of checkBlacklist');
                $event->block();
        }
            
        }
        catch(\Throwable $e){
           $this->loggerHelper->logThrowable($e, 'Failed to send block the email in subscriber ');
        }

    }
}
```